# How do I use a google apps script in another spreadsheet?

Tags: google-apps-script

I made a lot of functions to use in google docs spreadsheet.

I also saved this script as version 1.
I also made a deployment and it got installed as an add-on. But this does not appear in Add-ons.

I also made a new script file not associated with a spreadsheet and pasted in same code.

I can import it as a library into another spreadsheet and use functions in script, but I can not use functions in spreadsheet cells.

eg. if library has a function pc_rand(), I want to put '=pc_rand()' into a cell. Or, '=lib.pc_rand()'

How do I to use this script in another google docs spreadsheet?

Comment: If you want to obtain the same result of the script for Spreadsheet "A" at the Spreadsheet "B", for example, how about using the script as a library? But if this was not the direction you expect, I apologize.

Comment: That's what I want: to be able to use script functions in spreadsheet B. I have since tried a library and I can write new functions that use library functions but I can't use library functions in spreadsheets. eg in cell A1 I want =pchatalib2.pc_rand()

Comment: Thank you for replying. When you want to use the functions in Spreadsheet "A" for the Spreadsheet "B" as the custom functions, unfortunately, in the current stage, `=pchatalib2.pc_rand()` cannot be directly used. So in this case, it is required to create a function like `const pc_rand = () => pchatalib2.pc_rand();` in the script editor of the Spreadsheet "B" and put `=pc_rand()` in a cell. I apologize for this.

Comment: Hi Tanaike, could you write this as an answer so we can upvote and OP accept? If you want I can make a community wiki answer in your name

Comment: @Raserhin Thank you for your comment. From your suggestion, I could post it as an answer. Thank you for your always support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to obtain the same result of the script for Spreadsheet "A" at the Spreadsheet "B".

In order to achieve your goal, I would like to suggest to use a Google Apps Script library. When the script of Spreadsheet "A" is used as the Google Apps Script library, the same result with the Spreadsheet "A" can be obtained at the Spreadsheet "B" by calling the script from Spreadsheet "B".

But, from [your replying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65032772/how-do-i-use-a-google-apps-script-in-another-spreadsheet#comment114972912_65032772), there is an important point for this. When you want to use the functions in Spreadsheet "A" for the Spreadsheet "B" as the custom functions, unfortunately, in the current stage, `=pchatalib2.pc_rand()` cannot be directly used. (In this case, it supposes that `pchatalib2` and `pc_rand()` are the library identification and the function of the library, respectively.) So, in this case, it is required to create a function in the script editor of Spreadsheet "B" as follows.

```
const pc_rand = () => pchatalib2.pc_rand();
```

By this, when `=pc_rand()` is put in a cell, the function of Spreadsheet "A" can be run at the Spreadsheet "B".

#### References:

- [Libraries](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/libraries)
- [Custom Functions in Google Sheets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions)

Comment: Answer, currently, really is that it can't be done without replicating function definitions and jsDoc statements for autoComplete. So, easier to copy and paste all functions into new spreadsheet.

Comment: @philcolbourn Thank you for replying. I agree with your comment. For example, when you want to copy the script to the Spreadsheet as the container-bound script using a script, you can also use Google Apps Script API. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/reference/rest/v1/projects)